# System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript only getting executed once

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint, code-behind, scriptmanager

I have a weird problem. I use JavaScript on a Sharepoint page. I reference following JavaScript code:

```
var statusId = '';
var notifyId = '';

function AddNotification(message) {
    notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(message, true);
}

function RemoveNotification() {
    SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
    notifyId  = '';
}

function AddStatus(message) {
    statusId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus(message);
    SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(statusId, 'red');
}

function RemoveLastStatus() {
    SP.UI.Status.removeStatus(statusId);
    statusId = '';
}

function RemoveAllStatus() {
    SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
}
```

Then when the user clicks a button, a notification should appear with the message "please wait...". Before the calling C# method exits, it should remove the notification. Like this:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Notif", "AddNotification('" + Core.Classes.ResourceHelper.LoadResource(Core.Classes.ResourceName.PleaseWaitString) + "');", true);
       //Busiess logic...
       if (ActivityDate.SelectedDate == null || //Date required
           ActivityProjectnumber.SelectedIndex == 0 || //Project number required
           ActivityActivity.Text == string.Empty || //Activity description required
           EndTime.SelectedDate.Hour < StartTime.SelectedDate.Hour ||    //
           EndTime.SelectedDate.Hour == StartTime.SelectedDate.Hour &&   //Start time should not be less or equal end time
           EndTime.SelectedDate.Minute <= StartTime.SelectedDate.Minute) //
       {
           StatusSetter.SetPageStatus(Core.Classes.ResourceHelper.LoadResource(Core.Classes.ResourceName.CheckRequiredFieldsString), Core.Classes.ResourceHelper.LoadResource(Core.Classes.ResourceName.WarningString), this.Controls);
           return;
       }

       //If business logic passed, save item.
       SaveItem();

       System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Notif", "RemoveNotification();", true); //Problem lies here...
}
```

The notification is displayed when the user clicks the button. But it doesn't disappear. I debugged the code and the corresponding line is definitely being executed. I suspect it has something to do with me using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` two times in one method. But I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give different names to each script (the 3rd parameter of RegisterStartupScript).